# How can I make a back button appear only if the user navigated to the page from my website?

Tags: javascript, jquery

If the user goes to a specific page on a website from another page, I want a back button to appear. If someone just typed in the url of that page, it shouldn't appear. How can I do that with js? I tried setting a variable on one page that is true if I navigated, but the problem is that I can't read the value of the variable on the other page.

Comment: Store the variable in a cookie. That will be stored and you can load it on the next page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`document.referrer` gives you the URL (if any) of the previous page.

In general, if you are trying to pass information from page to page, see [window.localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps using window.referrer attribute can help solve your issue. In case you just typed in that url, this attribute will be undefined. Otherwise, it will contain the url of the page that sent you to your new page.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is the referrer, which you can get using `document.referrer`.

Then, just check the referrer's domain name matches yours using a regex.

Comment: Seems @Stefan K answered quicker :p

Answer (score 0):

It's a little complex than other answers, but it can help you.

You can use local Storage or local session - sometimes working with cookie is difficult. On button click add in local storage current URL. Then on the next page you can check for the value exists

```
if (!!localStorage["Url"]) {
    // You have a prev page URL
}

$('body').on('click', 'a', function(){
      localStorage["Url"] = document.location;
})
```